# Upgrading a project to use a higher version of NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, nvm

I have a project currently configured to run NodeJS `v10.x.x`, but I want to upgrade it to run on version `12.16.1` to be consistent with other projects I am working on and so that I do not have to use [nvm](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/) dozens of times throughout the day.

My package.json contains:

```
{
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.x.x"
  },
  ...
}
```

If I change this to `12.x.x` and build an error is thrown by a package in `node_modules` (the `grpc` package which I am *not* directly referencing in my `package.json`).

**Question:** I want to upgrade the packages in my `package.json` to the lowest versions required to be able to run Node `v12.16.1`, which hopefully will reduce the number of breaking changes caused by the upgrade. I want the minimal amount of changes possible.

Is there a good way to approach this? Other than updating one package to the latest version, trying to build, then repeating this process until it works.

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: What approach did you end up taking to achieve this?

Comment: @BrendanMoore I can't remember. However, I'd say the best approach is to upgrade all your projects to the latest LTS version of node if possible. Then upgrade your packages to the latest release; this is the tricky part as you are going to have to check the change logs for each package. I'd recommend checking the changelogs for the major version increases - e.g. if you're going from SomePackage v4.2.3 to v.6.0.1, check the release logs for v5 and v6 as these should state any breaking changes regarding support for NodeJS versions. It's a pretty significant undertaking on big projects.